# elegant increment operator as pipeline

Tags: r, operators, increment, pipeline

```
library(magrittr)
x <- 2
x %<>% 
  add(3) %>% 
  subtract(1)
x
```

Is there predefined a more readable way that works with pipes?

Perhaps something like `x %+=% 3 %-=% 1`

Comment: That *is* the predefined way, chosen by the authors of magrittr. They created those functions.

Comment: Can you even do this in languages that have built-in increment operators?

Answer (score 5):

#### The short answer

No.

#### The long answer

Incrementing operators are easy to make:

```
%+=% <- function (x, inc) x + inc
%-=% <- function (x, dec) x - dec
```

However, these functions don't modify `x` directly because R tries very hard to prevent functions from modifying variables outside their scope. That is, you still need to write `x <- x %+=% 1` to actually update `x`.

The `inc<-` and `dec<-` functions from package `Hmisc` work around this restriction. So you might be surprised to find that the definition of `inc<-` is just:

```
function (x, value) 
{
    x + value
}
```

That is, the code inside the function is exactly the same as in our custom `%+=%` operator. The magic happens because of a special feature in the R parser, which interprets

```
inc(x) <- 1
```

as

```
x <- `inc<-`(x, 1)
```

This is how you're able to do things like `names(iris) <- letters[length(iris)]`.

`%<>%` is magical because it modifies `x` outside its scope. It is also very much against R's coding paradigm*. For that reason, the machinery required is complicated. To implement `%+=%` the way you'd like, you would need to reverse-engineer `%<>%`. Might be worth raising as a feature request on their GitHub, though.

*Unless you're a `data.table` user in which case there's no hope for you anyway.

Comment: To modify in place, one option is `\`%+=%\` <- function(x,y) assign(deparse(substitute(x)),x+y,.GlobalEnv)`, though probably with something else in place of `.GlobalEnv` to be less unsafe. By the way, no `data.table` user would ask to use pipes like this.

Comment: @Frank fair enough. I was thinking of `:=` when I wrote that.

Comment: Oh, you're right about that, and there are a whole host of functions named like `set*` that also modify in place. I just meant that your caveat "*Unless you're a..." is probably not needed, since the OP is almost surely not one.

Comment: AFAICT `%<>%` from magrittr does *not* modify in place, rather rewrites the result back to the original variable (it only masks the assignment). The two are very different things.

Comment: @Arun yup, that's what it's _actually_ doing. But the effect for the end user is the same

Comment: Sorry again, but why is it (`%<>%`) then against R's coding paradigm?

Comment: @Arun "[R, at its heart, is a functional programming language](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html)," and [there are good reasons to avoid side effects in functional programming](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/15269/143380).

Comment: I understand all that. What has that got to do with %<>% if we both agree that it doesn't modify in place?

Comment: It's a function with a side effect. I'm going to edit my post to clarify